# How do I use different compilation standards in QNX Momentics 6.5?

Tags: c, gcc, qnx, qnx-neutrino, momentics

I'm trying to build applications for the Sabre i.MX6 development board, that runs QNX OS. I'm using QNX Momentics v6.5 for cross-compiling my code. I wrote a simple "Hello World" code and I'm trying to compile it with new c standards since the project I'm working on requires that.

When I try to compile with any flag, say `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`, it throws an error during the compilation saying

`cc: unknown Option -std=c99" or "cc: unknown Option -std=c11"`.

I can see that the compiler it's using is `gcc 4.4.2`.

I'm not sure whether this version of `gcc` doesn't support `c99` or whether the flag I'm passing is supposed to be different for QNX Momentics.

Comment: Can you try `-Wc,-std=c11`?

Comment: @Ctx It's still showing the same error. -Wc does not cause any error. What's that flag for?

Comment: Passing an argument specifically to the compiler, but I already suspected that it is a no-op in this case.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: did you modify the Makefile, or editted the build properties? for me in sdp7.0 its working.

Comment: @thomachan I added the flag to additional compilation options in build properties and I could see it reflect in the Makefile. But the error during compilation.

Comment: @Arvind, I amusing Momentics 7.0 for imx8x, I am able to use -std=c99 for armv7le.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QNX 6.5 and gcc 4.4.2 don't support C++11.  See [the QCC docs](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities/q/qcc.html) for more info.
The best you'll get is incomplete and experimental support through `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gun++0x`.

QNX 6.6 includes gcc 4.7.3 which does have experimental C++11 support and QNX 7.0 uses gcc 5.4.0 has full C++11 and C++14 support.

Full details of the gcc C++ standards support can be found [on the gcc standards page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html).

Comment: How about c11? Because that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not supported in QNX 6.5...  Have to upgrade to at least 6.6.  You may want to dig around on foundry27... there used to be some more up to date tools (even though they are unofficial and unsupported).

Comment: Thanks for the info! But my project requires working with a legacy device running this specific version of QNX.

Comment: Maybe QNX can help but I doubt it.  You can build a newer version of gcc and libc if you really want... it might be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

QNX 6.5 doesn't support C++11 out of the box, since it is using an old GNU compiler (gcc 4.4.2). However, the QNX Software Center has several updates to QNX 6.5 that will let you update to GCC 4.8.3, which will get you pretty decent C++11 support.
You will need to create an account on the QNX website and then:

1. Download Binutils 2.24 for your host (e.g. win32-binutils-2.24.zip for WIndows) from http://community.qnx.com/sf/frs/do/listReleases/projects.toolchain/frs.binutils.
2. Download GCC 4.8.3 for your host (e.g. win32-gcc-4.8.3-qnx65x.zip for Windows) from http://community.qnx.com/sf/frs/do/viewRelease/projects.toolchain/frs.gcc.gcc_4_8.
3. Expand both archives - this will create `host` and `target` folders.
4. Copy & paste new folders into QNX folder, overwrite files.
5. Edit `host/win32/x86/etc/qcc/gcc/default` to change the default compiler: `DIR=4.8.3`

When compiling add the following flags:

- `-Vgcc_ntox86_gpp` to QCC (for an x86 target) to get gcc 4.8.3 headers.
- `-Wc,-std=c++11` to QCC to make it use C++ 11.

Comment: did you have an idea why the STLs, like <String> are broken with qnx 6.6 in win32 GCC 4.8.3 for armlev7 ? With v. 4.7.3 (Default) i can still compile.